# Heap use after free when using shared pointers

Tags: c++, heap-memory, shared-ptr, address-sanitizer

I keep getting heap use after a free error when I try to pass a shared pointer to a class object.

Firstly, my tree builder has the root as a private field:

```
class ExpressionTree{
private:
std::shared_ptr<ASTNode> root;
public:
std::shared_ptr<ASTNode> getRoot();
void build(std::string expression);
}
```

ASTNode for reference:

```
class ASTNode {
public:
    virtual ~ASTNode() = default;
    virtual void accept(ASTVisitor& visitor, ElementMap elements) = 0;
};
```

The build function (using the shunting yard algorithm) stores nodes in a dequeue:

```
 std::deque<std::shared_ptr<ASTNode>> nodeStack;
std::deque<std::string> operatorStack;
```

For example, for a binary operator (a class deriving from `ASTNode`):

```
auto right = nodeStack.back();
nodeStack.pop_back();
auto left= nodeStack.back();
nodeStack.pop_back();

root = std::make_shared<BinaryOperator>(operatorStack.back(), left, right);
operatorStack.pop_back();
nodeStack.emplace_back(std::move(root));
```

After the shunting yard algorithm goes through all the tokens, I move the root:

```
root = std::move(nodeStack.back());
```

I have a vector of game "rules" (stored as strings) and I am trying to store them into `"Rule"` classes that I have. The issue is in the `"When"` rule. My interpreter is where I use the tree builder and construct the "When" object:

```
ExpressionTree expressionTree;
    for (auto rule: rules_from_json->getVector()){
        if(ruleName == "when"){
        std::vector<std::pair<std::shared_ptr<ASTNode>, RuleVector>> conditionExpressionRulePairs;
        
        ElementVector cases = rule->getMapElement("cases")->getVector();
        for(auto caseRulePair : cases){
        
        std::string conditionString = caseRulePair->getMapElement("condition")->getString();
        expressionTree.build(conditionString);
        std::shared_ptr<ASTNode> conditionExpressionRoot = expressionTree.getRoot();
        
        RuleVector caseRules;
        toRuleVec(game, caseRulePair->getMapElement("rules"), caseRules);
        conditionExpressionRulePairs.push_back({conditionExpressionRoot, caseRules});
        }
        
        ruleObject = std::make_shared<When>(conditionExpressionRulePairs);
        }
    } //freed here
```

The error shows that std::shared_ptr is freed at the last brace of the above snippet.

This is the when rule:

```
class When : public Rule {
    std::shared_ptr<ASTNode> conditionRoot;

    std::map<std::shared_ptr<ASTNode>, RuleVector> condition_rule_pairs;
    std::map<std::shared_ptr<ASTNode>, RuleVector>::iterator condition_rule_pair;
    
    RuleVector::iterator rule;
    bool match = false;

public: 
    When(std::map<std::shared_ptr<ASTNode>, RuleVector>& conditon_rule_pairs);
    bool executeImpl(ElementSptr element, ElementMap elementsMap) final;
    void resetImpl() final;
};
```

All the other rules are working and are able to pass a visitor to the root correctly. The only difference here is that I'm storing the roots for each case in a vector and passing that in:

```
//rules.cpp in the `execute` function of the `when` rule
for (; conditionExpression_rule_pair != conditionExpression_rule_pairs.end(); conditionExpression_rule_pair++) {
conditionRoot = conditionExpression_rule_pair->first; //**this line gives the error**
conditionRoot->accept(resolver, elementsMap);
```

The error:

```
AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x00010a902690 at pc 0x000104f83ec4 bp 0x00016b488550 sp 0x00016b488548
#0 0x104f83ec0 in std::__1::shared_ptr<ASTNode>::shared_ptr(std::__1::shared_ptr<ASTNode> const&) memory:3125
#1 0x104f687a4 in std::__1::shared_ptr<ASTNode>::shared_ptr(std::__1::shared_ptr<ASTNode> const&) memory:3127
#2 0x104f716b8 in std::__1::shared_ptr<ASTNode>::operator=(std::__1::shared_ptr<ASTNode> const&) memory:3246
#3 0x104f6fe34 in When::executeImpl(std::__1::shared_ptr<ListElement>, std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::shared_ptr<ListElement>, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const, std::__1::shared_ptr<ListElement> > > >) rules.cpp:105
```

The thing is, I tried to pass a visitor to the root in the constructor and it works:

```
When::When(std::vector<std::pair<std::shared_ptr<ASTNode>&,RuleVector>>& conditionExpression_rule_pairs)

: conditionExpression_rule_pairs(conditionExpression_rule_pairs), 

conditionExpression_rule_pair(conditionExpression_rule_pairs.begin()),

rule(conditionExpression_rule_pair->second.begin()) {

TreePrinter t; //a visitor just to pretty print nodes
ElementMap elementsMap;
for(auto it : conditionExpression_rule_pairs){
it.first->accept(t, elementsMap);
std::cout << std::endl;

}
}
```

So somehow, the root exists in the `when constructor` but not in the `when execute` because it has been freed from the heap. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the roots are all stored in a vector because for the other rules, I just pass in a singular root and the constructor assigns it to another root like for example, the `foreach` rule :

```
Foreach::Foreach(std::shared_ptr<ASTNode> listExpressionRoot, RuleVector _rules, std::string elementName)
: listExpressionRoot(listExpressionRoot), rules(_rules), elementName(elementName) {
}
```

In the `foreach`, I can access the root in the `execute` function and pass a visitor, and so on.

I tried everything but cannot seem to get rid of this error in the `when` rule. Please help.

Comment: `for (auto rule: rules_from_json->getVector())` -- `for(auto caseRulePair : cases)` -- The lack of using references looks suspicious.  You are working with temporary copies on each iteration of those loops.

Comment: That wasn't it. Good point though.

Comment: `rules_from_json->getVector()` -- Does this return a reference or a copy of the vector?

Comment: It returns a copy. However, the rules_from_json vector is just used to get the string such as at "condition" and build an expression tree from those strings to store into the rule objects. Just like "when", I am constructing other rules like 'foreach' and passing 'std::shared_ptr<ASTNode>' into the constructor. It works properly for all other rules. The only difference in 'when' is I am passing a vector ('conditionExpressionRulePairs') instead of just the root. So I don't think it is related to rules_from_json.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: Long term storage of iterators is always suspicious – in particular iterators that are easily invalidated, such as vector iterators. (Iterators are meant for transient use, such as iteration.) And undefined behaviour may manifest itself in an apparently unrelated way much later, or even earlier, than when it occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot believe this. I spent a week on this and made posts to two different forums.

TURNS OUT:

```
rule(conditionExpression_rule_pair->second.begin())
```

in the initializer list of the When constructor, was using `conditionExpression_rule_pair` from the constructor argument:

```
When::When(std::vector<std::pair<std::shared_ptr<ASTNode>&,RuleVector>>& conditionExpression_rule_pairs)
```

instead of the actual field from the when rule. So obviously that vector got deleted when the constructor went out of scope and the iterator would be pointing to nothing.

Comment: It can help to name the parameters and the member variables differently. We in our company use a leading underscore for member variable names (and then continue with a lowercase letter; those identifiers are standard compliant to the naming rules of the C++ standard). One can still use the wrong one (parameter instead of member variable), but at least it is save to move code between other member functions and the constructor without changing semantics.